# Removing navigation button on a GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

My app uses a `GoogleMap`.  One of my testers reports that on his new Galaxy Tab 4 running Android 5.0.2, the map has a button on it which launches Google navigation.  I did not put that button there, and I don't see it on any of my devices.

How do I get rid of that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got more details from the tester.  The button only appears when a marker is clicked.  I disabled it by setting a marker click listener that consumes the event and does nothing:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }
});
```